# Pyqgis Gdal_translate

Tags: python, pyqgis

I would like to transform tifs in a directory with using python in qgis 3 in order to make tifs with a diffrent crs and adding tfw file.

```
import glob, os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import *
import processing
input_f = r'C:\Users\48515\Documents\t1'
output_f = r'C:\Users\48515\Documents\t2'
count  = 0
for raster in glob.glob(input_f + "/*.tif"):

    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster,baseName)

    print(processing.algorithmHelp("gdal:translate"))
    trans = os.path.join(output_f,baseName + "_image_"+str(count)+".tif") 
    processing.run('gdal:translate',
                   {'INPUT':raster,
                   'TARGET_CRS':'ESPG:2179',
                   'COPY_SUBDATASETS':0,
                   'DATA_TYPE':0,
                   'EXPAND':'1',
                   'TFW': 1,
                   'OUTPUT':trans})

    count += 1
    iface.addRasterLayer(raster,trans)
```

However, when i run this code, there aren't any changes. What I quess, there are wrong keys in processing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues in your code. First one is that you need administrator permission for writing in 'C:\Users\48515\Documents\t2'.

It is preferable to do:

```
.
.
.
input_f = r'C:\Users\Usuario\48515\Documents\t1'
output_f = r'C:\Users\Usuario\48515\Documents\t2'
.
.
.
```

Following issue is in 'TARGET_CRS':'EPSG:2179'. You have 'ESPG'. However, this only override CRS (there is not any reprojection).

So, following code fixes your main issues:

```
import glob, os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
import processing

input_f = r'C:\Users\Usuario\48515\Documents\t1'
output_f = r'C:\Users\Usuario\48515\Documents\t2'
count  = 0

for raster in glob.glob(input_f + "/*.tif"):

    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()

    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster, baseName)

    trans = os.path.join(output_f, baseName + "_image_" + str(count)+".tif") 

    processing.run('gdal:translate',
                   {'INPUT':rlayer,
                   'TARGET_CRS':'EPSG:2179',
                   'COPY_SUBDATASETS':0,
                   'DATA_TYPE':0,
                   'EXPAND':'1',
                   'TFW': 1,
                   'OUTPUT':trans})

    iface.addRasterLayer(trans, baseName + "_image_" + str(count))
    count += 1
```

After running above code at Python Console (with one raster in 'C:\Users\Usuario\48515\Documents\t1') it works as expected (see following image):

[image]